# scroll to top on load not working with me

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I want to scroll to top when the user refresh the page so I tried with below script.

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    $('html').scrollTop(0);
     })
```

And also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

and this too:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

the last one works but it show the page before the load start.

so any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to use `setTimeout()` to set the `scrollTop(0)` on page `load` event. Am not able to provide live example here, but surely it helps. Check below code.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout()

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
},50);
```